# Mvc3 Model with KnockoutJs ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm trying to find out how i can pass an Mvc 3 model (with pre-populated collections) to a Knockout ViewModel?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Jules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just populate it from your Razor view by writing all the mvc model values into related js objects. But I would rather load it via Ajax call after the page is loaded. Have a look at an idea here:
[Lazy loading an observable in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/lazy-loading-observable-in-knockoutjs.html).

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer. The MVC model must be populated first (client requirement). Do you have an example on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I've played with this Steve Sanderson demo "Editing a variable-length list, Knockout-style", but it's in Mvc2 and the "new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)" doesn't return the right format data.

Comment: Have you used your "JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)" directly in the view? If so you have to wrap it in @Html.Raw(). You can also extend your model and add ToJSON method: [ToJSON()](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx)
In case it doesn't work for you, I recently used Json.NET (Nuget: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json) to do similar things. Have a look [here](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since commenting. For the time being I'm just going to use Ajax requests to solve this. Thanks for your help.